# If C# attribute work like decorator design pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a question about attributes in C#, does it work like the decorator design pattern ? For example the `[HttpPost]`
attribute adds a behavior to call a decorated action ? or does it work differently ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Attributes, in general, does not change the behaviour of the method. They're additional metadata stored alongside the method. You can inspect those attributes, and then react to them, but without explicitly adding such inspection code, using reflection, attributes changes nothing. So no, it's not a decorator pattern as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare these two things. Attributes are used to be accessed via reflection. They don't change behaviour magically. You might probably (ab)use attributes to implement some kind of weird decorator design pattern. But just because an Attribute "decorates" e.g. a member, class, method or something, it has nothing to do with the decorator design pattern!